# Nvidia Optix Coordinate System

Tags: opengl, graphics, nvidia

What kind of coordinate system Nvidia OptiX Ray Tracer uses -- RHS or LHS ?

- I am using simple pinhole_camera.cu model as the ray generation program. ( if it matters at all)

Comment: NVIDIA OptiX does not have a definite coordinate system, that means you can modify according to your need. But to keep match with OpenGL, the samples come with SDK are using RHS coordinate system, came for your `pinhole_camera.cu`